# XPath to select multiple elements

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho-spoon

I have an XML as shown below:

```
<managedObject class="SUBRACK" version="1.0" distName="xxxx-xxxx/BSC-2222/xxx-102/xxx-1/xx-1" id="2222">
      <p name="locationName">000000-000</p>
      <p name="subrackSpecificType">xxxx</p>
      <p name="vendorName">xxxx</p>
      <p name="version">01</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="UNIT" version="1.0" distName="x1-X2/XXX-111111/YYY-102/ZZ-1/AAAA-1/BBBB-CCC_2_3" id="55555">
      <list name="availabilityStatus">
        <p>Power On</p> 
      </list>
      <p name="identificationCode">9999A</p>
      <p name="operationalState">1</p>
      <p name="position">1</p>
      <p name="serialNumber">8888B</p>
      <p name="unitId">1</p>
      <p name="unitType">HHHH</p>
      <p name="vendorName">AAAA</p>
      <p name="version">333</p>
    </managedObject>
```

I want an XPath to select all the **p name** along with their values.

**I am able to get** the other values using:

**@class** - to get class

**@version** - to get the version

.

.

***[name()='list']/*[name()='p']**  - to get "Power On"

***[name()='p']/@name** - to get *identificationCode* (first p name)

***[name()='p']** - to get the value of *identificationCode* - 9999A

Similar to the last two fields, I want to get the rest of the elements using XPath:

operationalState - 1

position - 1

serialNumber - 8888B

unitId - 1

. .

.
.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 locations where you specify an XPath expression in step Get-Data-From-XML:

1. The Loop XPath (Content tab) is meant to derive rows from a document by returning a nodelist.
2. The Field XPath (Fields tab) is meant to populate the fields of a row.

If your document contains multiple nodelists on different levels, it's best to aim for the deepest list.  It's easy to access ancestor information using axes or the `..` operator.

When a field XPath returns a nodelist, Kettle will always pick the first item instead of aborting.

Obviously you must use `//p` as your Loop XPath.

Comment: With a nodelist determined by a Loop XPath like `//p` you get the managedObject for free - just use an XPath expression like `ancestor::managedObject`

Comment: Thanks. Adding ".." worked. I was able to get all p name values.

Comment: Since your XML fragment shows element `p` on different levels the parent operator `..` might not be the best solution.

Comment: But I was able to get all the values by adding "*[name()='p']/.." as XPath in the Fields tab

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get required data from all `p` elements without specifying each `name` attribute value you can use

```
//list/following-sibling::p[@name]
```

or

```
//*[name()="list"]/following-sibling::*[name()="p" and @name]
```

If you want both `name` attribute value and text content of `p`:

```
//list/following-sibling::p[@name]/@name | //list/following-sibling::p[@name]
```

Comment: It gives an error saying:
Invalid XPath expression: *[name()='p']::p[@name] Unexpected '::'

Comment: Yes. Because it's really invalid expression. Check my answer again- there is nothing similar to `*[name()='p']::p[@name]`

Comment: As I mentioned before:
*[name()='p'] gets the value of identificationCode - "9999A"

Comment: It should return values from all paragraphs (`p`) on page. What exact output you want to get?

Comment: Until now,  I am only able to get: 
<p name="identificationCode">9999A</p>

I want the rest of the fields too:
<p name="operationalState">1</p>
      <p name="position">1</p>
      <p name="serialNumber">8888B</p>
      <p name="unitId">1</p>
      <p name="unitType">HHHH</p>
      <p name="vendorName">AAAA</p>
      <p name="version">333</p>

But I am only getting the first p element

Answer (score 0):

You can try following xpath to retrieve any "p" element in xml with specific "name" attribute no matter where its located in xml.

```
//p[@name='unitType']
```

Here `//` is the descendant-or-self. Just replace unitType string in above xpath with desired one.
Output of above xpath selection will be

```
<p name="unitType">HHHH</p>
```